# Cycling through threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to do a client server exercise in Python and it has to be concurrent, so basically I got a main server and 3 other download servers. These download servers connect just fine to the main one but whenever I want to interact with them I just can't. I tried to cycle through the threads and execute a simple function that sends a different message from the main server to each of the download ones. The problem is that it only sends the message to the last one it cycles through, and it doesn't even send the right message, it sends the message meant to be delivered to the first server to the last one.

So here's my code:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import logging

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Thread Pool
class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        print "[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port)

    def run(self):
        while True :
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            print "Server received data:", data
            #MESSAGE = raw_input("Multithreaded Python server : Enter Response from Server/Enter exit:")
            if not data:
                break
            if data == 'exit':
                break
            #conn.send(MESSAGE)  # echo


class DServerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port


    def run(self):
        while True :
            data = conn.recv(2048)
            print "Server received data:", data
            if not data:
                break
            if data == 'exit':
                break
            #conn.send(MESSAGE)  # echo

    def sendmsg(self,str):
        conn.send(str)

# Multithreaded Python server : TCP Server Socket Program Stub
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 2004
sport = 5000
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  


dServer=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
dServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
dServer.bind((TCP_IP, sport))
tcpServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpServer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpServer.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
cthreads = [] #client threads
sthreads = [] #download server threads
controlthreads = [] #Threads to manage the background processes

for i in range(1, 4):
    dServer.listen(3)
    (conn, (ip,port)) = dServer.accept()
    newthread = DServerThread(ip,port)
    newthread.start()
    sthreads.append(newthread)



for t in sthreads:
    print t.getName()
    t.sendmsg(t.getName())
```

The problem to me is on that last loop, but I don't quite get why.

TL;DR: Last loop isn't working as intended, it seems to only execute the function on the last iteration and send the message meant for the first thread.

Comment: The `conn` object you are using in the threads is a single global variable. You are overwriting it in the for loop each time.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much.